# $\inf \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ when $x^2+y^2\le 1$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$\inf\limits_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\min\limits_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\}} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$$$=\sqrt{\min\limits_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\le 1\}} (x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt0=0$ (since $x^2+y^2\ge 0$).

I was wondering if there is more to this argument to make it more rigorous or elegant?

Comment: I would just observe that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq 0$ with equality occurring if and only if $x=y=0$. Since this point lies within the region of interest, you are done.

Comment: I'd say that it is trivial that $\;\inf\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{0+0}=0 ....$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the polar coordinate system we have $\inf\limits_{r\in\mathbb{R}:0\leq r\le 1} r=\min\limits_{r\in\mathbb{R}:0 \leq r\le 1} r=0$

Comment: I do not know how to make it simpler than this.